# Cannot activate windows, must upgrade windows 10 pro to windows 10 pro

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

My Windows 10 pro suddenly got deactivated.

Why?

When I go into settings and Activation Settings in windows 10 pro, I get a message reading

> Edition Windows 10 Pro
> Activation Windows is not activated
>
> We can't activate Windows on this device as the product key you
> entered doesn't match the hardware profile. If you recently repaired
> Windows or made significant hardware changes to this device, select
> Troubleshoot to try and fix the problem or go to the Store to buy
> genuine Windows. Error code: 0xC004F034.

So I click that link and a dialog comes up that after a couple of seconds. It sais

> Troubleshooting has completed
>
> We found a Windows 10 pro digital license for this device running
> Windows 10 Pro. To activate using this digital license, select upgrade
> your edition of Windows.

I clicked the link, the dialog shows the text

> Upgrade your edition of windows This might take a while. Don't turn
> off your PC. 0% complete.

...but the dialog closes after a couple of seconds, the percentage still being 0%. The computer restarts.
Nothing more happens. If I enter the Activation settings, nothing is changed.

- I have not done any significant hardware changes (half a year ago, I bought two new hard drives).
- The windows 10 pro version I have is an upgraded Windows 7 from the time where there was an offer to upgrade windows 7 to windows 10 freely.

So I need to upgrade windows 10 pro to windows 10 pro?

What is that?

Comment: Try to run command line "slmgr /dlv" to check system version type and activation status. As Windows 10 activation information is associate your hardware with Microsoft activation server, we could reinstall it to get a automatically activation.

Comment: I solved this by buying a new license...

Answer (score 2):

Something went very wrong with Windows. I suggest:

1. Check the disk SMART data for degradation
2. Run `chkdsk`
3. Run
   [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
   and the DISM command in the link
4. If all fails, do the "upgrade" by
   [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I always advice to take a backup image of the system disk before a major upgrade, and have a restore boot media available, just in case Windows won't boot afterward.